# Using InstallShield Limited Edition with VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installshield

Is the InstallShield LE integrated with a purchased key of Visual Studio 2010? The information was limited in the web searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. 
I've been using it and InstallShield installer is independent from Visual Studio. You should sign up in InstallShield website in order to get a key to activate it.

Hope it helps.